# Is it possible, or advisable to install the block chain on an external ssd drive via a laptop and USB port

Tags: trading

I am thinking of getting back to using bitcoin and am looking at the most convenient way to do so. I would like to know if it is possible to install the block chain on an external ssd drive, running it via the USB port using a laptop and an ssd storage device. Is this a viable way to run bitcoin transactions?
If so, then what spec should I be looking for when buying a laptop?

Craig

Comment: IIRC, external drives have an increased occurrence of read and write errors, so you'd be likely to have issues with corrupted blocks.